# Find the nearest bigger number in R

Tags: r, numeric

I have a dataset like this:

```
row  num Group
  1 3     B
  2 6     A
  3 12    A
  4 15    B
  5 16    A
  6 18    A
  7 20    B
  8 25    A
  9 27    B
 10 29    B
```

In R,
I would like to compare an input number with the values in **num**, and I would like to find the location of the closest bigger value in **Group A** only.

For example, if the input number is 8, then the closest, bigger value in group A should be 12, and I would like to get its location which should be 3. If the input is 18, then the value returned should be 18, and the location should be 6. If the input is 20, then the value returned should be 25, and the location should be 8.

I tried which.min, but for some reason, index 1 is always returned regardless of my imput number.

```
#called the dataset f

which.min(f$num[f$Group=="A"][f$num[f$Group=="A"]>=8])
```

I would like to still use base R if possible
I would appreciate any thoughts on which part I did wrong and how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to be able to handle an input where there’s no higher value, and if so what would you want the return value to be in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ifelse()` to replace elements that don’t meet your conditions with `NA`, then use `which.min()` on the resulting vector:

```
which.min(ifelse(f$Group == "A" & f$num >= 8, f$num, NA))
# 3

which.min(ifelse(f$Group == "A" & f$num >= 18, f$num, NA))
# 6
```

Part of the reason your solution doesn’t work is that by subsetting, you change the element positions, so the position returned by `which.min()` doesn’t correspond to your original vector. By replacing with `NA`s instead, you preserve the original positions.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, if my input variable is larger than 13 it returned integer(0) for some reason

Comment: That doesn’t happen for me. Are you testing it in the same example dataset? If not, does the dataset you’re using have any values >13 in group A?

Answer (score 1):

As for nearest bigger num, you could formulate the function:

```
nearest_bigger_num <- function(num, vec) {
  which(min(vec[num < vec]) == vec)
}

nearest_bigger_num(8, df$num)
## 3
```

However, in your case, you want to even count the group.

```
nearest_bigger_num_in_group <- function(num, df, group) {
  df <- df[df$group == group]
  df <- df[num < df$num]
  df$row[which.min(df$num)]
}

nearest_bigger_num_in_group(8, df, "A")
## 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here two ways to do it

### `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
  data.frame(
    row = 1:10,
    num = cumsum(rep(3,10)),
    group = c("B","A","A","B","A","A","B","A","B","B")
  )

df %>% 
  filter(num >= 8) %>% 
  slice_min(order_by = row)

  row num group
1   3   9     A
```

### Base R

```
df[min(df$row[(df$num >= 8)]),]

  row num group
1   3   9     A
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I would like to use base R if possible. I tried what you post, but unfortunately it did not limited the comparison to group A, I believe.